# Get value during JQuery change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select menu where when I click a button it populates. This menu then has an on change event where it changes the div below it with whatever is in it. The problem is the first value doesn't work because it isn't a "change".

HTML/PHP Before:

```
<select>
 <option>Pre Fill</option>
</select>
```

HTML/PHP After:

```
<option value="<?=$row["ID"]?>"><?=$row["Person"]?></option>
```

THE PROBLEM

```
function FillList(str) {
    $.get( "get.php?q="+str, function( data ) {
      $( "select" ).html( data );
});
    var Id = $('select').val();
    $.get( "fill.php?q="+Id, function( data ) {
        $( ".Info_Div" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

For my `var Id` it returns Pre Fill instead of the first results ID number. I know I can just throw in a blank space so people have to change it. But is there a way I can get it to do it instantly? My change works, the first result doesn't work unless I change off it and change back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the `.change()` event after the `<select>` is loaded. It will then run the code that updates the value in the other `<div>`.

```
$.get( "get.php?q="+str, function( data ) {
  $( "select" ).html( data ).change();
});
```

Also, `$.get` is asynchronous, which means it won't pause the execution of the script until the response has returned, instead it will continue to execute the statements below. For `Id` to contain something from the response, it must be inside the response callback.

```
$.get( "get.php?q="+str, function( data ) {
    $( "select" ).html( data ).change();
    var Id = $('select').val();
    $.get( "fill.php?q="+Id, function( data ) {
        $( ".Info_Div" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your should call your function in

> $().ready();

block so it will called right after your document loaded

Answer (score -1):

Common problem.  Most common solution:

```
<select>
    <option>Choose:</option>
<?php
    While Loop
        <option value="<?=$row["ID"]?>"><?=$row["Person"]?></option>
        <option value="<?=$row["ID"]?>"><?=$row["Person"]?></option>
        <option value="<?=$row["ID"]?>"><?=$row["Person"]?></option>
    EndWhile
?>
</select>
```

You can also use the `.blur()` event to detect the user leaving the control and grab the value at that point.

Comment: They want the `select` to be populated when a button is clicked, not when the page is loaded.

Comment: This would work, I just wanted to avoid using the empty option.